# Получение данных частями из большой таблицы MySQL (LIMIT и OFSET)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Есть таблица, которая содержит около ~200 млн. строк. Вот DDL:

```
create table KeyPropertyIndex
    (
      EntityPropertyId bigint default '0'       not null,
      Value                varchar(1000) default '' not null,
      EntityIds            varbinary(800)           null,
      primary key (EntityPropertyId, Value)
    );
```

Из Java кода мне нужно забирать из нее данные и делать какую-то бизнес логику с ними. Естественно нужно забирать их частями, чтобы не упасть по памяти. Первое, что приходит в голову использовать `LIMIT` и `OFSET`. Но, наткнулся на статью: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset где данную конструкцию не рекомендуют к использованию, т.к. она сильно замедляет выборку, а вместо этого предлагают использовать `WHERE` по автоинкрементному полю, т.е. по некому `id`. Но как быть в моем случае, ведь у меня нет данного поля и модифицировать я данную таблицу никак не могу.

Comment: используйте свой первичный ключ. Выбирайте записи в сортировке по нему и смотрите на чем остановились. следующий поиск можно делать примерно по такому условию `where (EntityPropertyId=X and Value>Y) or EntityPropertyId>X` где X и Y последние запомненные EntityPropertyId и Value. только план выполнения стоит посмотреть, or не самая идеальная конструкция

Comment: После сортировки по первичному ключу надо выбрать поле `rownum`, оно должно присутствовать в таблице или его туда надо добавить.

Comment: @Mike *следующий поиск можно делать примерно по такому условию* Думаю, разумнее делать выборку по простому `EntityPropertyId>=X`, а ранее обработанные `Value` отбрасывать на клиенте (а ещё лучше - не обрабатывать возможно неполный набор для последнего `EntityPropertyId`, а сразу "подчитывать" следующий блок данных).

Comment: @Mike, не совсем пониманию, как нужно делать выборку. Допустим мне нужно отобрать первые N записей, потом следующие N и.т.д. до конца таблицы. Как это можно сделать? `LIMIT` и `OFSET` в данном случае более понятен.

Comment: выбираете записи с `limit N`, при следующей выборке задаете условия в where исходя из того какую запись последнюю видели, а лимит так же N ставите

Comment: @Mike, только боюсь, что для такого обхода нужно будет добавить в таблицу суррогатный ключ (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87)

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Я особой необходимости в нем не вижу. условия из моего первого комментария должны нормально отработать. Главное что бы оптимизатор не слишком сильно на OR обиделся. Как вариант, если на один EntityPropertyId не особо много value, делал бы limit с некоторым запасом и не шел бы до конца выбранного, если далее EntityPropertyId не изменяется. С таким расчетом, что бы каждую выборку делать строго по EntityPropertyId>X (где X последнее обработанное). Хотя малость костыльно выглядит